# Increasing network range for new VOIP users

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, voip

Our office using 192.168.1.0 /24 for DHCP 120 users and reserved 20 IP for servers and 10 IP for network printers.

Now management decided to upgrade to VOIP phones for all users so I need to make some changes on network. But, all the users desk will have only one data point so both VOIP phone and PC need to share which means desk Cat 6 cable will connect to VOIP phone port and Phone's PC port is connect to PC Ethernet port. I have 3 options to choose so please correct me which is the best for me?

Option 1: Shall I increase network to /22? I will move VOIP phones and PC to 192.168.2.0/22 and all servers and network printers will remain the same static IP address range 192.168.1.0/22 . Now all the PCs are grabbing IP address from DHCP server so after changing network to /22 so I strongly believe that I need to change new subnet on DHCP. Can I disable the existing scope since I am going to use static IP address (192.168.1.x) for servers and Printers and shall I create New Scope (192.168.2.1-192.168.2.250) for new VOIP Phones and PCs? Or remain the existing scope (192.168.1.0/22) and just add a new scope (192.168.2.0/22) ?

Option 2: Shall I use VLAN for PCs and Phones so I don't need to change new subnet on all servers? But, I am not sure how to configure on 3Com VLAN supported managed switch and I am not sure whether this VLAN can use for one Ethernet cable sharing for VOIP+PCs with two ip addresses?

Option 3: I will just change /22 subnet and all the PCs will remain the same ip address (192.168.1.0) which will grab IP from DHCP server and I will use static IP address for VOIP Phones (192.168.2.0). I am not sure whether I can use two different segments for one data point which mean VOIP phone will use .2 and Servers/Pcs/Netowrk printers will remain .1 network?

Please advice me. Thanks a lot. It's a hard time for me.

Comment: Typically, you will want the VoIP phones on their own subnet and VLAN. Separation of the VoIP and data traffic will help stabilize VoIP and ease your QoS deployment.

Comment: Option 2 is your best bet. The VoIP should be able to deal with VLAN tags and use one for itself and pass through the other vlan to the PC. We have this setup running at the moment and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.1.0/22 and 192.168.2.0/22 are the same thing.  Actually, they are both part of 192.168.0.0/22 which covers all addresses from 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.3.255

Consult a Variable-Length Subnetting Chart ("VLSM chart") for easy visual assistance on understanding how one subnet contains the same addresses of multiple other subnets.

Basically, a /24 contains 256 addresses.  A /23 contains twice what a /24 has, and a /22 contains twice what a /23 has.

You can have two DHCP scopes simultaneously.  If the devices (e.g., PCs) don't need to communicate with each other, that may even be the smoothest way to introduce a transition.  e.g.: place new equipment on 192.168.4.0/22 (192.168.4.0 through 192.168.7.255), which means subnet mask "255.255.252.0".  For critical equipment like the routers, place them on 192.168.0.0/21 (subnet mask 255.255.248.0, so they can communicate with 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.7.255) during the time of the transition; then you can move them to 192.168.4.0/22 (subnet mask 255.255.252.0) after the transition is done.  Devices on the old subnet ought to work until they renew their DHCP lease; they can renew their release (often by restarting the device) if you want them on the new subnet sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want VoIP phones sharing a layer-2 domain with your regular data traffic. A common solution for what you have is to create separate VoIP and data VLANs, each with their own network addressing. This prevents all the PC/Server/Printer traffic from hindering the VoIP traffic which is particularly sensitive to jitter. It also makes it easier to build your QoS policies, which are particularly important to have if you are using VoIP.

Most VoIP phones which have data ports for connecting PCs are really switches internally. This allows them to trunk to the switch and connect separate data and VoIP VLANs. Many switches can use LLDP or CDP to automatically negotiate this trunk, or you can configure the trunk on the switch port.